# In Meteor how can I load the page links without subscribing to all the page content?

Tags: meteor

I want to load all the links to my pages. What I did it, created a seperate subscription with only the `slug` and `title` fields. Used this data in my navigation and it worked. But now I need to subscribe on every single page with all the fields. The problem is, it's showing only the slug and title fields. I think the two subscriptions are conflicting. Here's my subscriptions :

```
Meteor.publish("pageLinks", function() {
    return Pages.find({}, {
        fields: {
            title: 1,
            slug: 1
        }
    });
});

Meteor.publish("page", function(slug) {
    check(slug, String);
    return Pages.findOne({
        slug: slug
    });
});
```

And my subscriptions in the route for the single page :

```
FlowRouter.route('/page/:slug', {
    name: 'pageSingle',
    subscriptions: function(params, queryParams) {
        this.register('page', Meteor.subscribe('page', params.slug));
    },
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render('panelLayout', {
            content: 'pageSingle'
        });
        setTitle('Page');
    }
});
```

For the links, I subscribed in the template like this :

```
Template.panelLinks.onCreated(function() {    
    this.autorun(function() {
        Meteor.subscribe('pageLinks');
    });
});

Template.panelLinks.helpers({
    pageLinks: function() {
        return Pages.find({});
    }
});
```

Here's how I display the links :

```
    {{#each pageLinks}}
        {{> pageLink}}
    {{/each}}
```

What is the best way to solve this conflict and load all the fields of a page only in that page's route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is mistake in your publish function:

```
Meteor.publish("page", function(slug) {
    check(slug, String);
    return Pages.findOne({
        slug: slug
    });
});
```

You should see in console error :

```
Error: Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors
```

Replace `Pages.findOne` with `Pages.find`

---

If you correct mistake then you should be able to use different subscriptions of the same collection (Pages) and receive correct data.